# How to search a calendar event va Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: events, search, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I cannot find a way to look for a calendar event matching a given text (my own application-specific ID, that I would like to store in the calendar event body for instance):

- the `search/query` API is not supported for personal accounts (see https://stackoverflow.a/questions/66198537/authenticationerror-with-microsoft-graph-search-query-with-some-accounts-but-c)
- the `me/calendar/events` API does not support `$search`
- the `me/calendarview` API ignores the `$search` parameter : it silently returns the same big event list regardless of the criteria specified in `$search`. I could loop on all the event list for the one matching my criteria, but this is suboptimal and might lead to a huge traffic over the network, as I would have to first retrieve the full list of the users' event to loop on it!

Would you have any suggestion to query an event containing a given text? Or any other alternative approach?

Many thanks!

Comment: How about using startwith of $filter ?

Comment: Thanks Stanley unfortunately it does not help, because the events might be any time, like 2 years before or 2 years later. So it might still match a lot of other events. And I could not find other $filter options that would look for a text in the body btw.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this? Even though the CalendarView documentation refers to OData query, I am seeing the same result, where $search returns the same regardless.

Comment: @Carl: no, I did it another way, by finding the event with its ID. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't help me in this instance as I want to search body, but thank you for taking the time to respond.